# DateTime from C# an hour late?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

My client application requires, from the server, "how many seconds between some value and 1970".

I'm testing this with the following code:

```
var span = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;

return span;
```

But if I convert the result from this unix time, I get something that's an hour later than now, so my client application is not behaving as expected.

What's going on?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `ToLocalTime()`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I get 4 hours before now

Comment: Why don't you do this all in UTC and let the client care about the timezone?

Comment: When you think about it, you want to subtract "1/1/1970 0:0:0 UTC" from the current date/time. So you'd better put the current date/time into UTC first, and the same with 1/1/1970.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var span = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

return span;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with UTC times:

```
(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0));
```

Then use span.TotalSeconds